# I have some query about Admob policies

Tags: java, android, adsense, admob

Actually, I am integrating interstitial ads on my `recyclerview adapter` so whenever the user clicks on an item of recyclerview then Interstitial ads will appear and **onClosed method of ads my detail activity will start**.

so the main question is, is this as per `Google AdMob Policies` **because each and every time ads will start when user click on any item of the recyclerview?**

If this is not as per AdMob policies plz provide your suggestion/answers, so that my ads can work as per `Google AdMob Policies`

> Thank you in advance ☺

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion For Placing Ads,

**Your AdPlacement should not overlay(or)disturb the content**

In your case it is interstial ad which will be display on full screen when user clicks any item.It is not privacy violation you can proceed with your AdPlacement.